# Need to know the format which supports Chinese and Thai language in mpdf using Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, format, mpdf

While generating the PDF in the codeigniter php for multiple languages such as chinese and Thai language it doesn't support the language format in the final pdf. The generated output is displayed as ▯▯▯▯▯.

```
    $pdf=new \mPDF('+aCJK','A4','','',15,10,16,10,10,10);

        $pdf->useOnlyCoreFonts = true;    // false is default
        $pdf->SetProtection(array('print'));
        //$pdf->autoScriptToLang();
        $pdf->SetWatermarkText("Rentokil Initial");
        $pdf->showWatermarkText = true;
        $pdf->watermark_font = 'dejavusanscondensed';
        $pdf->watermarkTextAlpha = 0.03;
        $pdf->shrink_tables_to_fit=0;


        $pdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
        $pdf->baseScript = 1;
        $pdf->SetFont('cid0cs','',16);
        $pdf->CSSselectMedia = 'pdf';
        $pdf->charset_in = 'UTF-8';

        $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $pdf->Output($pdfFilePath,"F");
```

Above is my current scenario for generating pdf, but this doesn't support Chinese and Thai language format. The expected output is not in the correct format "▯▯▯▯▯". Please let me know how to fix this below format issue or help me to share the format which supports Chinese and Thai language.

[My current PDF Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhDCH.png)

Comment: UTF-8 is fine, but ensure that `$html` is also in UTF-8 before adding to the pdf.

Comment: The DejaVu fonts are a font family support  thai and chinese in mPDF, you will need to download the font file and save it to a location on your server. Then, you can use the $pdf->SetFont() function to specify the font that you want to use.
 `$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans','',12);`
You may also need to sett the charset_in property to UTF-8 to ensure that mPDF can correctly interpret the charaacters in your HTML :
`$pdf->charset_in = 'UTF-8';`

Comment: Hi @AliUsama tried both the ways still facing the same issue. once I convert the downloaded pdf to word then i can view in the chinese language. Cant able to fix this only in pdf format.

Comment: **@LavanyaSuresh** Try setting the `useOnlyCoreFonts` property to `false`. Or try using a different PDF library like TCPDF